# Vue.js + Nuxt.js: Can't connect with socket server using socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io, nuxt.js

I am using for client and server sides: socket.io-client v3.0.5

**index.vue**

```
import socket from '~/plugins/socket.js'

<script>
    mounted() {
        socket.open()
    }
</script>
```

**plugins/socket.js**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const options = {
  path: '/socket.io',
  transports: ['websocket'],
  forceNew: true,
  reconnectionAttempts: 3,
  timeout: 2000,
  reconnection: false,
}
const socket = io(process.env.PROXY_SOCKET_URL, options)

export default socket
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/socket.js',
],
```

And on mount i got this: [2 commas after '40' code in data of ws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTCzo.png)

My client side and server side not connecting because of 2 commas in data. I tested my socket server via SocketIo Client tool and it works.
My frontend and backend in docker.

How can i remove those commas?

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing with this the past few days, and have a module-free solution.

In order to run the socket.io server on the same server that nuxt is providing we need to get access to Nuxt's server. Luckily, Nuxt's *listen* hook provides the server once it has been started. We can use this server to start our socket.io server by adding the following to `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
import startSocketServer from "./server/sockets"

defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
  hooks: { listen: (server) => startSocketServer(server) },
  ...
})
```

and inside of `~/server/sockets/index.ts` we export a function that accepts this server and spins up the socket.io server:

```
import { Server as NuxtServer } from 'node:http'
import {  Socket, Server } from "socket.io";

export default (nuxtServer: NuxtServer) => {
  const io = new Server(nuxtServer)
  io.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => {
    socket.emit('message', "Hello World")
  });
};
```

That's it for the server!

If we now have an app.vue that looks like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io();
onMounted(() => socket.connect());
onUnmounted(() => socket.close());

const message = ref("");
socket.on("message", (data: string) => (message.value = data));
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ message }}</div>
</template>
```

We should see "Hello world" from the server when we load the page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in production, only in dev mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have sockets enabled in nginx/apache or whatever you're using to serve/proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "nuxt-socket-io"(v1.1.18) module instead of socket.io-client. It helped me connect front and server.

Here my realization:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
modules: [
    'nuxt-socket-io',
],
io: {
    // module options
    sockets: [
      {
        name: 'main',
        default: true,
        url: process.env.PROXY_SOCKET_URL,
      },
    ],
  },
```

**index.vue**

```
<script>
    mounted() {
      window.socket = this.$nuxtSocket({
        path: '/socket.io',
        transport: ['websocket'],
      })
      window.socket.open()
    }
</script>
```