# How to emit on a websocket attached to a Nuxt 3 server

Tags: javascript, socket.io, nuxt3

Learning from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74762176/11258206) response, I attached a websocket server to the Nuxt 3 server.

Now I want to emit from a different server file.

In particular, I have an endpoint that receives webhook and I want to update the client based on the posted data by the webhook, before returning `ok` to the webhook post request.

By inspecting the event object of the `defineEventHandler` function, I found out that there are `event.node.req.socket.emit` and `event.node.res.socket.emit` functions.

However, by using them, nothing is emitted and if I `console.log` it, I get `false`.

This is my code:

- ./nuxt.config.js

```js
import startSocketServer from "./server/sockets"

export default defineNuxtConfig({
...
  hooks: {
    listen: (nuxtServer) => startSocketServer(nuxtServer)
  },
...
});
```

- ./server/sockets/index.js

```js
import {  Server } from "socket.io";

export default (nuxtServer) => {

  const io = new Server(nuxtServer);
  
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  
    console.log(`connection ${socket.id}`);
  });
};
```

- ./server/socket.post.js

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

  const { invoiceId, type }  = await readBody(event);

  console.log(event.node.res.socket.emit(invoiceId, type));
  
  event.node.req.socket.emit(invoiceId, type);

  return 'ok';
})
```

Which is the correct way to emit with websocket in this case?

Comment: Note that `listen` hook only runs in dev server, so this approach is not suitable for production use.

Answer (score 0):

The solution wasmuch easier then expected in the end:

- ./server/sockets/index.js

```js
import {  Server } from "socket.io";

export let io;

export default (nuxtServer) => {

  io = new Server(nuxtServer);
  
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  
    console.log(`connection ${socket.id}`);
  });
};
```

- ./server/socket.post.js

```js
import { io } from '../server/socket/index.js'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

  const { invoiceId, type }  = await readBody(event);
  
  io.emit(invoiceId, type);

  return 'ok';
})
```

- ./nuxt.config.js remains the same as in the question.